# Combining two Linq Expressions

Tags: c#, linq

Using info from various SO posts and notably this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx) (corrected to use `AndAlso` rather than `And`) I've managed to combine similarly typed linq expressions into a single predicate. But now I want to combine two Expressions where one is an input to the other. Here's the fully expanded original `Expression`;

```
    private Expression<Func<T, bool>> ExpressionIsNamed(IEnumerable<EntityName> AccessorNames)
    {
        // works
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> Texpr = x => x.Security.Readers.Any(n => AccessorNames.ToStringArray().Contains(n.Text));

        return Texpr;
    }
```

Note that crucially, I need to manage these as **Expressions** because my DB driver needs to walk the tree and convert into a native call so using **Compile()** to combine is not an option.

So below is the function I want to combine with the `Any()` call above. The final output Expression needs to be of type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and I need to pass `x.Security.Readers` into this one.

```
    public static Expression<Func<IEnumerable<EntityName>,bool>> AccessCheckExpression(IEnumerable<EntityName> AccessorNames)
    {
        return accessList => accessList.Any(n => AccessorNames.ToStringArray().Contains(n.Text));
    }
```

I've got as far as this, but I'm struggling to work out how to swap out `accessList =>` from `accessCheck` and have it use `accessList` in a single Expression. So far, I have this;

```
    private Expression<Func<T, bool>> ExpressionIsNamed(IEnumerable<EntityName> AccessorNames)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<EntityName>>> accessList = (T x) => x.Security.Readers;
        Expression<Func<IEnumerable<EntityName>, bool>> accessCheck = SecurityDescriptor.AccessCheckExpression(AccessorNames);

        // Combine?
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> Texpr = ??? accessCheck + accessList ???

        return Texpr;
    }
```

**[Update]**

So I've got a little further;

```
    class ParameterUpdateVisitor : System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private ParameterExpression _oldParameter;
        private ParameterExpression _newParameter;

        public ParameterUpdateVisitor(ParameterExpression oldParameter, ParameterExpression newParameter)
        {
            _oldParameter = oldParameter;
            _newParameter = newParameter;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(node, _oldParameter))
                return _newParameter;

            return base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }

    static Expression<Func<T, bool>> UpdateParameter<T>(
        Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<EntityName>>> expr,
        ParameterExpression newParameter)
    {
        var visitor = new ParameterUpdateVisitor(expr.Parameters[0], newParameter);
        var body = visitor.Visit(expr.Body);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, newParameter);
    }
```

I can then compile with;

```
UpdateParameter(accessList, accessCheck.Parameters[0]);
```

Thanks to all for those `Invoke()` suggestions, but my guess is that by the time they get to the MongoDB driver it won't like `InvocationExpression`. However, both `Invoke` and my code above now fail in exactly the same way. Namely;

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 
'System.Func`2[MyLib.Project,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyLib.EntityName]]' 
cannot be used for parameter of type 
                            'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyLib.EntityName]'
```

So it would appear that the implicit parameter `x.Security.Readers` is a different type to a plain old `IEnumerable<EntityName>`

Comment: You missed type parameter in `ExpressionIsNamed` definition.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Not necessarily. They generic parameter could be defined on the class containing this private method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`VisitorExpression` is your friend here. Here's a simplified but complete example of merging something similar:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Source {
    public List<Value> Values {get;set;}
}
class Value {
    public int FinalValue {get;set;}
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Expression<Func<Source, IEnumerable<Value>>> f1 =
            source => source.Values;
        Expression<Func<IEnumerable<Value>, bool>> f2 =
            vals => vals.Any(v => v.FinalValue == 3);

        // change the p0 from f2 => f1
        var body = SwapVisitor.Swap(f2.Body, f2.Parameters[0], f1.Body);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Source, bool>>(body,f1.Parameters);
        // which is:
        // source => source.Values.Any(v => (v.FinalValue == 3))
    }

}
class SwapVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    private SwapVisitor(Expression from, Expression to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public static Expression Swap(Expression body,
        Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        return new SwapVisitor(from, to).Visit(body);
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
         return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Edit: in your case, this would be:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> ExpressionIsNamed(
    IEnumerable<EntityName> AccessorNames)
{
    Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<EntityName>>> accessList =
        (T x) => x.Security.Readers;
    Expression<Func<IEnumerable<EntityName>, bool>> accessCheck =
        SecurityDescriptor.AccessCheckExpression(AccessorNames);


    var body = SwapVisitor.Swap(accessCheck.Body,
        accessCheck.Parameters[0], accessList.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, accessList.Parameters);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have something similar working (see my udpated post), but I've a different problem relating to mismatched IEnumerable types.

Comment: @cirrus you haven't merged them correctly; let me edit, to show the above in the context of your code...

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! Not only did that compile and run, it didn't barf in the DB Driver either (which was the reason I needed to combine the Expressions) and I have a column of passed tests to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's going to work, but try this:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> ExpressionIsNamed(IEnumerable<EntityName> AccessorNames)
{
    Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<EntityName>>> accessList = (x) => x.Security.Readers;
    Expression<Func<IEnumerable<EntityName>, bool>> accessCheck = AccessCheckExpression(AccessorNames);

    var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Invoke(accessCheck, accessList.Body), // make invokation of accessCheck, and provide body of accessList (x.Security.Readers) as parameter
        accessList.Parameters.First() // parameter
    );

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Invoke is unreliable; it doesn't work on all providers - EF notoriously hated Invoke, and presumably still does.